# Radio Livewire Laravel - Cant get the radio value

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

this code is from my resources/views/collection

```
<livewire:frontend.product.index :category="$category"/>
```

its binding with livewire to livewire/frontend/product/index

```
<div class="card-header bg-white mt-3">
                <h4>Price</h4>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <label class="d-block" for="">
                        <input type="radio" name="priceSort" class="me-3" wire:model="priceInput"
                            value="high-to-low">High to Low

                            check : {{var_export(($priceInput))}}
                    </label>
                    <label class="d-block" for="">
                        <input type="radio" name="priceSort" class="me-3" wire:model="priceInput"
                            value="low-to-high">Low to High
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>
```

i want to get the "low-to-high" value from the radio but it seems like the
`check : {{var_export(($priceInput))}}` is null
[image: var export img null]

here is my livewire controller code

```
class Index extends Component
{
    public $category, $products;

    public $priceInput;

return view('livewire.frontend.product.index', [
            'products' => $this->products,
            'category' => $this->category,
        ]);
}
```

thanks for the answer

Comment: Could you share your complete Livewire component code? The class looks incomplete here - looks like you're missing a function definition

Comment: yes i did, i miss the @livewireStyles in the main thanks before

Answer (score 1):

its solved, i already found it i need to input

```
 @livewireStyles
```

in the `<head>`

and

```
@livewireScripts
```

in the `<body>`